# How do I attach file (image, audio, text) in mail application of android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to attach file in my mail app. but all time only body has been sent. I am using method:

```
 public void addAttachment(String path) throws Exception
    {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();  
        DataSource dataSource = new FileDataSource(path);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(path);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }
```

I have used two jar file mail.jar, activation.jar. mail body is working fine. but attachment is not reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method looks the exact same as what I use and works.

But what I want to know is how you're calling the method?

```
message.addAttachment("./sdcard/img.jpg);
```

Or something like that?

Comment: - I use to call before the mail message method send like 

sender.attachment("/sdcard/1307101479886.jpg");
sender.sendMail(subject.getText().toString(),body.getText().toString(), from.getText().toString(), to.getText().toString());